# How to get webpage link address

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm loading an webpage from my application and keep on browsing and move to some other page, at any point i want to store current web page link address in my string field. any idea..? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe You can receive it by javascript:
    <script>
    var currentUrl=document.URL
    </script> 

Also you can store value in the session instance or something like that. But i have no experience in android webview, i answered as i did in python app for android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its possible, if you have implemented **[WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html)**.

You can detect URL inside shouldOverrideUrlLoading() method:

```
browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // You can have URL here
    }
});
```